# Knockout two way Binding for Dropdrown

Tags: binding, knockout.js, html-select

I am facing the issue while binding the value for dropdown from a observable array.

- Model

  ```
  function question(item)
  {
      var self = this;
      self.questionId = ko.observable(item.questionId || "");
      self.position = ko.observable(item.position || "");
      self.position.subscribe(function (data) {
         // Some Logic
      }, this, 'beforeChange');    

      api.position.subscribe(function (data) {
      // Some Logic
      }
  }
  ```
- View Model

  ```
  function viewmodel(item)
  {
      var self = this;
      self.questionList = ko.observableArray([]);
      self.questionEntity = ko.observable(new question(item)); 
      // initially Item will be blank
      self.addQuestion = function(data)
      {
          data.position(self.questionList().length + 1);
          self.questionList.push(data);
      }
  }
  ```
- View

  ```
  <div>
     question Id : <input type="text" data-bind="value: questionEntity().questionId "  >
     <button data-bind='click: $root.addquestion'>Add Question</button>
  </div>

  <table>
     <tbody data-bind='foreach: questionList '>
     question Id : <span data-bind='text:questionId' ></span>
     position : 
        <select data-bind='options: $root.positionList,optionsText: "id",optionsValue: "id" ,value: position'></select>
     </tbody>
   </table>
  ```
- Problem

I have one popup div(`addQuestion`) and I will add the question. and I am keep on adding that question to my observable Array(`questionList`)

When i add First question my value in observable array is

```
questionId | Position
1          | 1
```

When I add second record

```
questionId | Position
1          | 1
2          | 2
```

When I Add thrid record, all the previous records POSITION value(value is binded to dropdown) is being reset to 1 except last record

```
questionId | Position
1          | 1
2          | 1
3          | 3
```

fourth record

```
questionId | Position
1          | 1
2          | 1
3          | 1
4          | 4
```

after debugging I found out its problem with two way binding with Dropdown

```
<select data-bind='options: $root.positionList,optionsText: "id",optionsValue: "id" ,value: position'></select>
```

in above code if change the binding(single way) like below it works fine

```
<select data-bind='options: $root.positionList,optionsText: "id",optionsValue: "id" ,value: position()'></select>
```

But I need to subscribe an event for the dropdown.

Comment: Position is changing somehow because it is an observable. Therefore, changing value in your select to postion() will work, but it will ruin your events. As to your actual problem, look and see how position changes? Maybe add a subscribe to position and console log the current value to see how it changes?